# Deleting embed after reaction is added

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
message.channel.send(embed).then(async function(message) {
  await message.react(create);
  await message.react(edit);
  await message.react(del);
  await message.react(search);
  await message.react(cancel);
}).then(async function(message) {
  bot.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    reaction.remove(user);
    switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
      case create:
        break;
      case edit:
        break;
      case del:
        break;
      case search:
        break;

      case cancel:
        if (cancel.count === 2)
          message.channel.bulkDelete(5);
        break;

      default:
        return;
    }
    return;
  });
});
```

I was wondering how could I delete the embed, since using `message.channel.bulkDelete(5);` or anything like that only deletes the emoji reaction.
I want to delete the full embed that is sent once the cancel emoji has been added by a user.

Comment: Hi, I've edited your code formatting and now it's clear that it's incomplete, please fix that. Also, please annotate what does that code do and what "embed" you are talking about, for now the question is not quite clear. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is not with [`TextChannel.bulkDelete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete), but with the `switch` statement. You're checking `if (cancel.count === 2)`, but `cancel` is not a [`MessageReaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction): you should be checking `if (reaction.count === 2)`.

Also, [`TextChannel.bulkDelete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) **does** delete messages, so it's better if you use [`message.delete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete) instead.